# Adding more tables to search after a where clause in a Inner join clause

Tags: inner-join, where-clause, multiple-columns, clause

Please help me with this query. I have included as much info as possible about this.
Here is my Query:

```html
<?php
$sql4 = ('SELECT *,COUNT(*) FROM tt_new_make
inner join tt_new_size
ON tt_new_size.no=tt_new_make.no
inner join
tt_new_rub
on tt_new_rub.no=tt_new_make.no
WHERE tt_new_size.s_line_no1="12R" GROUP BY m_line_no1, line_no1');
?>
```

My results are not what I am looking for. I know that I am limiting my coding with being too specific with the s_line_no1="12R", but how do I include all columns? 
[tt_new_size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rirXm.jpg)
My results should be 4, not 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the problem was on the way I post it to the table. 
I should have post everything under 1 row, not on multiple columns.
The results should look as follow:

[Table layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grTYg.jpg)